# SQL - Select Only Players and Dates When a Date Does Not Contain a Player

Tags: sql

`select player,date from nba.player_stats
where tm='NOP';`

This returns a column of NBA players for the New Orleans Pelicans and a column of dates of games that the players played in. There are multiple players for each date. When a player gets hurt and does not play, the player does not show up in the player column for that specific date.

I'm trying to write a query where I can say something like WHERE player='Ryan Anderson' does not exist, return those dates and the list of players that played on those dates. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Sorry, I'm having trouble formatting the table. It is listed like so, except with more dates included:

```
**Player------------Date**

Ryan Anderson   2014-01-01

Jrue Holiday    2014-01-01

Anthony Davis   2014-01-01

Tyreke Evans    2014-01-01

Anthony Morrow  2014-01-01

Eric Gordon 2014-01-01

Brian Roberts   2014-01-01

Jeff Withey 2014-01-01

Darius Miller   2014-01-01

Al-Farouq Aminu 2014-01-01

Austin Rivers   2014-01-01

Alexis Ajinca   2014-01-01

Greg Stiemsma   2014-01-01

Alexis Ajinca   2014-01-04

Eric Gordon 2014-01-04

Jrue Holiday    2014-01-04

Tyreke Evans    2014-01-04

Al-Farouq Aminu 2014-01-04

Anthony Davis   2014-01-04

Brian Roberts   2014-01-04

Jeff Withey 2014-01-04

Greg Stiemsma   2014-01-04

Darius Miller   2014-01-04
```

Comment: Can you show the table structure, and perhaps sample data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will show all players that played on dates when Ryan Anderson did not play

```
select player, date 
from nba.player_stats
where date not in (select date 
  from nba.player_stats 
  where player = 'Ryan Anderson')
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to write the query, here are a few examples (all selecting NOP players that played when Ryan Anderson did not);

Using NOT IN, just check dates where he plays and exclude those;

```
SELECT player, date
FROM player_stats
WHERE tm = 'NOP'
 AND date NOT IN (
   SELECT date FROM player_stats WHERE player='Ryan Anderson'
 );
```

Using NOT EXISTS, exclude rows where there's a player with the same date and the name 'Ryan Anderson';

```
SELECT player, date
FROM player_stats
WHERE tm = 'NOP'
 AND NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 FROM player_stats ps
   WHERE player='Ryan Anderson' AND player_stats.date = ps.date
 );
```

Using LEFT JOIN, try to match with a player named 'Ryan Anderson' and the same date, display if no match;

```
SELECT ps.player, ps.date
FROM player_stats ps
LEFT JOIN player_stats ps2
  ON ps2.player='Ryan Anderson' AND ps.date = ps2.date
WHERE ps.tm = 'NOP' AND ps2.player IS NULL
```

[A simple SQLfiddle to test all of them](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dd88a/1).

Answer (score 0):

I think below will do the trick, try if that works:

```
select player,date from nba.player_stats
where date not in (select date from nba.player_status where player='Ryan Anderson') order by date desc;
```